# How can I see the XP amount of my assist and what is the maximum level they can get?

Tags: valdis-story-abyssal-city

I can't find anywhere a progress XP bar (like my character has) for my Assists.
How can I know how many times I need to summon them before they level up?
I want to prevent summoning them for nothing if they have already reached their maximum level.

Answer (score 0):

All Assists max out at your level. There is no XP bar for them as far as I can tell, but their level is tied to you character level.

Assist levels cannot go past a certain point until you reach specific character levels. For example, no matter how much you use them you won't get an Assist to level 5 while you are still level 1. Unfortunately I do not know the exact level break down on exactly what level you need to be to get assists to level 2, 3, etc. and haven't been able to find it. On the other hand I do know that the higher level your character is the faster your Assists level up. At level 20 you can get an Assist from level 1 to 2 within a couple of uses.

As for the effects of leveling Assists that varies based on the Assist but generally I've found you get a shorter cooldown, larger effect (whatever that effect may be), more damage, and for some (noticed this specifically on Shadowboxer and Atalan) the Assist attack changes slightly.

Comment: I'm partly disagree.
base on my experience, when I stand in a screen full with enemies that can't reach me and I'm used Faolan (when my MP was not full at least), I could spam his assistance couple of time until he level up (without directly contacting any enemy). I still don't know if you can't reach level 5 when you just level 1 or so, but that's not the point. I ask who could I know how much more do I need to use my assistance to until the next level. and you didn't answer that.

Comment: Yes, using an assist while enemies are on the screen levels up the assist weather you actually hit enemies or not. Did I say something to suggest otherwise? because that is not what I intended.

Comment: The short answer to your question is no that information is not available at this point. Unfortunately because the amount of assist uses needed to level changes with character level and assist level ups are gated by character level it is hard to just count how many times you used an assist before it leveled up. As far as I have seen no one has posted any numbers on this.